# JavaScript regex with this symbol "^" need to grab all numbers surrounding it

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to grab all digits before and after the "^" symbol, until it runs into any characters other than a digit stop. I tried this with a for loop but I'm having a little bit of trouble.

```
function equal(e) {
var last = [],
    string = values.innerHTML;
for(var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    if(/[\^]/.test(string[i])) {
       last.push(i);
    }
}

var storage = [],
    counter = 1,
    left = 0,
    right = 0,
    found = true,
    nums = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', '(', ')', '.', '^'],
    fullArr = [];

for(var i = 0; i < last.length; i++) {
    while(found) {
        if(nums.indexOf(string[last[i]+counter]) != -1 && nums.indexOf(string[last[i]-counter]) != -1) {
            right++;
            left++;
        } else if(nums.indexOf(string[last[i]-counter]) != -1) {
            left++;
        } else if(nums.indexOf(string[last[i]+counter]) != -1) {
            right++
        }
        if(nums.indexOf(string[last[i]+counter]) == -1 && nums.indexOf(string[last[i]-counter]) == -1) {
            storage.push([left, right]);
            counter = 1;
            left = 0;
            right = 0;
            break;
        }
        counter++;
    }
}

for(var i = 0; i < last.length; i++) {
    console.log(last[i] - storage[i][0], last[i] + (storage[i][1]+1));
    fullArr.push(string.slice(last[i] - storage[i][0], last[i] + (storage[i][1]+1)));
}
console.log(fullArr);
values.innerHTML = eval(values.innerHTML);
removeClass(e.target, 'special');
```

}

Comment: can you add: 1. example input, 2. expected result

Comment: I'm making calculator and I need to get that character "^" so I can place the numbers surrounding it like this for example:
22^2 would be Math.pow(22,2);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var mystr="123^345"+
"abc12^3456def\n"+
"abc^345\n"+
"^345\n"+
"345^\n"+
"345^def";
X=/([\d\.]+)?\^(\d+\.)?/img
while (mat=X.exec(mystr)){
    console.log( mat[1]+":"+mat[2])
}
```

---

**Output**

```
123:345
12:3456
undefined:345
undefined:345
345:undefined
345:undefined
```

Hope you can do the needful for `undefined` above.

Working example [here](https://repl.it/LTis/7).

**UPDATE**
I just noticed that you are using this for calculator then it would be as below:-

```
X=/([\d\.]+)\^([\d\.]+)/img
while (mat=X.exec(mystr)){
    console.log( mat[1]+":"+mat[2])
}
```

---

**Output**

```
123:345
12:3456
```

Working example [here](https://repl.it/LTis/8).

---

**UPDATE2**

```
X=/([\d\.]+)\^([\d\.]+)/img
while (mat=X.exec(mystr)){
    mystr=mystr.replace(mat[0],(Number(mat[1])**Number(mat[2])).toString())
}
console.log(mystr)
```

Working example [here](https://repl.it/LTis/10).

Comment: @Kyle.S would this work for you? I noticed that you were anyway using regex to find `^`, so you might as well use it for digits as well in one go, it would be faster too!

Comment: please see my updated answer I included the dot too, so that any decimal numbers will also be considered. Although I did not update the working example with the same, if you want let me know and I will update

Comment: Okay so now I need to replace those values with those two numbers how would I go about doing that? so for example this 2^2 would be 2:2?

Comment: You want to replace 2^2 with 4? Can be done give me a moment, stepped off computer.

Comment: "Do the needful" is not standard international English and probably won't even be understood by most English speakers outside of India.

Comment: Yes that's what I want because I need it to solve the problem then i'm just going to eval the rest of the string to handle + - etc. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @bulbus hey figured it out did this Math.pow(mat[1], mat[2])

Comment: If you're going to use `eval`, why not just translate the `^` into `**`?

Comment: @Kyle.S yes but see the usage of replace in code and also the sneaky `mat[0]`!

Comment: @torazaburo lol on `do the needful`. Completely agree, wanted to change it but by that time the OP's intention changed.

Comment: @Kyle.S if you are doing the whole hog of calculator then this is going to be a bit more messy as this does not handle negative numbers.. if you want I can edit to include +/- signs on numbers etc... but that will make regex a bit more complex

Comment: If you could I'd appreciate it

Comment: here you go, you need to replace the regex with [this](https://regex101.com/r/rvCst1/1/) complex one and you should be good to go!

Comment: @torazaburo disappointed as I was expecting to be corrected on **lol** :-)

Comment: not working for me for some reason here's the regex I'm inputting /(?:(?:\(([+-]?[\d\.]+)\))|([\d\.]+))\^\(?([+-]?[\d\.]+)\)?/g

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake now see [this](https://regex101.com/r/rvCst1/2). You can copy as is like you did earlier. If you liked the help please do upvote!

Comment: Please keep both simpler version and complex version handy, so that you can explain it easily.